# Why is root password disabled in SSH when the sudo user can do everything anyway?

Tags: ssh

I've started to use a Raspberry Pi in which the root user is not allowed to SSH in. The default user, pi, you are.

Unfortunately some scripts I use on a Centos machine for which I use root for was causing issues using the pi user.

I took the easy way and enabled root user.

But I am confused why it's disabled in the first place. Using sudo I could do everything root could anyway couldn't I? That's what it seemed.

But more importantly using sudo as pi I could enable root access anyway. So anyone using the pi user could do that.

So what's the point in disabling root password when I can use sudo or just easily enable it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I can see several reasons:

- It is first higly discouraged to use root user (reasons explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root)) and you shoud always prefer use sudo. In fact sudo follow the security principle i n which each user/application should only have the minimal required rights. If you use root account, all application will gain root rights, that are not required for all.
- ssh authorized users may not also be sudoers
- It's also recommended (as a best practice) to forbid password login and to allow passwordless authentication mechanisms such as ssh keys. In that case, even if an attacker can log in, he still has to guess the user password to execute sudo command.

**EDIT**

I forgot a reason, by looking at failed ssh logins in my logs, root is commonly used for bruteforcing.

Comment: Great thanks. The link to that other thread helped.. from my perspective the biggest issues are rm -Rf * ( I did this once about 8 years ago in / of a server, ouch!), and the other is running applications as root. So I understand both of these then, thats OK. But from a security perspective I cant see it an issue if I can login as pi and run sudo and then do it all, or enable root. So if anyone gets my pi login they can get root, so doesnt matter if they get root login.

Comment: But for my purposes, I want to run a custom script that writes to a root owned USB and I could not, so i think for my script its OK. Most times I can login as pi, but only when developing/testing/running my script I will use root. Thanks

Comment: As I said, if you use ssh keys, an attacker that gain access to your pi, will not have your user password . He then cannot execute sudo command.

However, you can specify a common user that he can run  `sudo YOURCOMMAND` without typing your password (and this only when executing this command) (cf. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password))

Comment: You can also limit what a sudo user can do.  As pointed out you can make it so the only elevated permission the user has, is to be able to run this single command, otherwise he has the same permissions as an unprivileged user